# How to write and save CSV file to server in PHP?

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to create a new CSV file using PHP and upload or move it to a new part of the server but the spreadsheet it returns is a spreadsheet that has only the first cell in the first row with a value of either 404 or 1. What am I doing wrong?

My code is attached below.

```
// genrate new general spreadsheet
$filepath = substr($file_path, 1);
$data = load_csv_file($filepath);

header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file-saved.csv"');

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'wb');

foreach ($data as $row) {
$output = fputcsv($fp, $row);
}

$filename = "file-saved.csv";
file_put_contents( $filename, $output);

fclose($fp);
```

The $data variable is an array of values from another CSV file.

Comment: Its now filling up an entire row with random numbers instead of just the first cell.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => DateTime
            [1] => Currency_Name
            [2] => Local_Date_Time
            [3] => Terminal_ID
            [4] => Merchant_ID
            [5] => Merchant_Name_Location
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08/06/2019 00:00:00
            [1] => USD
            [2] => 08/05/2019 02:05:23
            [3] => TEST
            [4] => 8124HSLA462288
            [5] => TEST DATA
        )
)

Comment: According to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php it returns length of written string (to handle, $fp). Perhaps you should save $fp and not $output.

Comment: … or write to an actual file on disk in the first place, instead of to `php://output` - depends on whether you want to _store_ the file in the server’s file system, or force a download. (Or both at the same time? Then you could still write to a normal file first, and read the content back from there [or just redirect to it] afterwards.)

Comment: I tried that too. It returned an empty CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$output = [];

foreach($data as $row) {
 $output[] = .. 
}
...
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by the addition of an explanation. In this case point out that the code you show is designed to collect output into the array `$output` and that the array should be processed at the end of the loop to go to the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
  error_reporting(0);
  $file_n = public_path('/csv_file/product_details.csv');
  $infoPath = pathinfo($file_n);
  if($infoPath['extension'] == 'csv'){
      $file = fopen($file_n, "r");

      $i = 0;
      $all_data = array();

          while ( ($filedata = fgetcsv($file, null, "|")) !==FALSE) {
            $num = count($filedata );
            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
              $all_data[$i][] = $filedata [$c];
            }
            $i++;
          }
          fclose($file);
          foreach($all_data as $importData){
            $insertData = array(
                   "article_number"=>$importData[0],
                   "article_name"=>$importData[1],
                   "article_description"=>$importData[2],
                   "article_price"=>$importData[3],
                   "article_manufacturer"=>$importData[6],
                   "article_productgroupkey"=>$importData[7],
                   "article_productgroup"=>$importData[8],
                   "article_ean"=>$importData[9],
                   "article_hbnr"=>$importData[10],
                   "article_shippingcosttext"=>$importData[11],
                   "article_amount"=>$importData[12],
                   "article_paymentinadvance"=>$importData[13],
                   "article_maxdeliveryamount"=>$importData[14],
                   "article_energyefficiencyclass"=>$importData[15]
            );

          insertData($insertData);
          }

  }else{
    echo "Invalid file extension.";
  }
```

function insertData($data){

if($article_number->count() == 0){

```
    //write your insert query here for $data
  }elseif($article_number->count() > 0){

   //article_number already present then update the table.UPDATE QUERY

  }
```

}